# What wears out a rubber sole of a shoe faster - sliding against dry or wet clay?

Tags: friction, everyday-life, material-science

This question arises from my daily experience as a tennis player.

I'm a novice to tribology. I couldn't quite come up with anything to answer that question. Any help?

I know for certain that the rubber sole of a tennis shoe wears out from sliding on clay, but I don't know what type of clay it happens faster sliding against - dry or wet. I assume that tennis clay is a softer material than rubber of a sole so it shouldn't be wearing the sole out. Or is the hard small particles of stone that are present in the tennis clay mainly responsible for the wear? I am also interested in the general physics of rubber against clay wear, and not just dry vs. wet.

The tennis clay I am talking about has the following consistency - small, about 1 mm width particles of stone together with red dust that becomes heavy and resembles clay when it absorbs water. Also, the case without any stone particles is interesting too - just red dust that is pressed into solid with a thin top layer of free dust that becomes clay when it absorbs water. Or you can google a pic of tennis clay if my description is bad

A player slides longer on dry clay - the dry clay has less friction. The clay is watered to allow more grip. However, as far as my brief research told me, there is no easy correlation between wear and friction.

Also, please feel free to direct me to some other forum if this isn't the most suitable place to discuss. And feel free to add relevant tags

Comment: Sounds like a good senior thesis experiment.